# postgres9.5: can't create extension on standby

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-extensions

I can't create extension on postgresql9.5 server (hot standby). During to attempting I received:

```
db=# create extension pgrowlocks;
ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE EXTENSION in a read-only transaction
```

Can anyone assist? Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says: the standby is **read-only** you can't run any statements on the standby that change things.

If you need the extension on the standby you need to create it on the master

Comment: On master extension already created. Replication is ok. But I can't see installed ext. on standby. Because of this I tried create ext. on standby.

Comment: @OlegAkchurin: does it show up in `pg_available_extensions`?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry. Replication is broken...(: